# Getting syntax error in Java code: Cannot cast from Object to int

Tags: java

I keep getting the syntactic error in Java code:

```
 Cannot cast from Object to int.
```

The problem code is like this:

```
int a = (int)obj;//obj is of Object type
```

But I have always been using this trick around, and only get the error recently.

My question:

1. Is this a real syntactic error?
2. Is there any configuration that can hide such syntactic error?.

Comment: What is the declared type of `obj`? How is it populated?

Answer (score 9):

`Object` to `int` is two steps - first you need to convert the `Object` to an `Integer`, then you need to convert the `Integer` to an `int`.

Fortunately auto-boxing will handle the second conversion for you, but you still need to explicitly make the first conversion:

```
 int a = (Integer)obj;
```

Comment: Be aware that autoboxing was introduce in Java 1.5. So it won't work with earlier version.

Answer (score 5):

You can't cast an object to an a primitive type, you need to cast to [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html?is-external=true):

```
Integer a = (Integer)obj;
```

Comment: Yea i know but i don't like it, just be specific for types.

Comment: You don't need to like it, it's better for OP in this case. he doesn't need `Integer`, `int` is enough.

Comment: @MarounMaroun We don't know that. He might be intending to stick it in a `List<Integer>`, and thus `Integer` would save him unneeded autoboxing/unboxing.

Comment: @jpmc26 For some reason I was sure OP wants `int`.. you're right :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun also the auto boxing introduce since Java 1.5, i think its more safe to do it like this :D.

Comment: @Salah there is no safety difference either way. 1.5 was introduced a long time ago. Yes if he was going to List<Integer> then you wouldn't want to box both ways. If he was going to int[] though then it wouldn't. More importantly if `a` was being used in calculations then you would potentially end up with a lot of autoboxing if you kept it as an `Integer`. It all depends what the questioner is going to be doing with the value.

Comment: @TimB Yea it depends, so we have to know what he want to do with a first then decide wich is better to use,anyway, i really respect you and your big experience and i know that i need a years to get that much of experience, but i don't know why such people just vote up for some answer just based on your name or if you have a big reputation, i don't meant youm but am saying for example, and i have just seen it many times. :S.

Comment: @Salah The reputation comes from the upvotes, not the other way around. It's taken me 4 months to get this reputation and I haven't noticed the upvotes per answer increasing as my rep does. I got more upvotes on this answer because I went into more detail than you did. You explained how. I explained both how and why.

Comment: @TimB Yea so at the end it depends, then we have to know the exact business for this variable, anyway, i don't know why there is some people just vote up for person names or its reputations, i have seen this many time :S. i don't mean you,whatever i respect your experience and i know i need years to get that much of experience.